# Trading View Indicator Testing

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

My conditions for a long signal are:

1. 8 EMA is above 14 EMA which is above 50 EMA
2. k line of stochastic RSI indicator should crossover d line of stochastic RSI indicator, i.e. k line should intersect d line from below
3. The cross over should occur when both k and d lines are below 70.

Code:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © junjinho1

//@version=5
indicator("3 EMA, Stochastic RSI, ATR", overlay=true)

//SMA
eight_EMA = ta.ema(close,8)
fourteen_EMA = ta.ema(close,14)
fifty_EMA = ta.ema(close,50)


//StoRSI
smoothK = input.int(3, minval=1)
smoothD = input.int(3, minval=1)
lengthRSI = input.int(14, minval=1)
lengthStoch = input.int(14, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="RSI Source")

rsi1 = ta.rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)

//conditions
longCondition = (eight_EMA > fourteen_EMA) and (fourteen_EMA > fifty_EMA) and (ta.crossover(k, d)) and (k < 70) and (d < 70)
shortCondition = (eight_EMA < fourteen_EMA) and (fourteen_EMA < fifty_EMA) and (ta.crossunder(k, d)) and (k > 30) and (d > 30)

alertcondition(longCondition, title = "Stochastic_RSI_Long", message = "Stochastic_RSI_Long")
alertcondition(shortCondition, title = "Stochastic_RSI_Short", message = "Stochastic_RSI_Short")
```

Sometimes, I find that the alerts I'm receiving do not accurately capture my intended conditions. E.g. there may be a crossover when condition (1) is not met, or condition (2) may be met, but the cross over is incorrect.

If any one could point out where I went wrong, I would be so grateful.

Comment: Is it possible for you to show the issue on a chart? So we can test it.

Comment: `eight_EMA > fourteen_EMA` does not check for crossover (you mentioned it many times) but only one being greater than the other. Examine these values closely at the point of your issue, as sometimes (it happened to me) this difference can happen on the 4th or 5th digit and the two values look almost the same visually.
As Pine lacks any built-in debug support, I suggest create some `plotchar()` function which displays a character above/below the bar if a condition is true. This way you can check when your conditions are met, individually.